# Pass a counter from a for loop into an event listener

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

I'm trying to pass the counter into an event listener's parameter function. I know it is possible using an anonymous function for the click event but wanted to use a named function instead. I can't seem to figure this out or if it is possible. Is there any way to do this?

```
function addKeys(){
    for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        keys[i].addEventListener("click", testing)
    }
}

function testing(e){
    console.log(e)
    console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) a parameter to the function:

```
keys[i].addEventListener("click", testing.bind(null, i))
```

Now `i` will be passed as the first parameter, before any others:

```
function testing(i, e) {
  ...
}
```